# CSS animation repeat for all animations

Tags: css, animation, count, iteration, repeat

I have a text animation as following. But I couldn't apply animation-iteration-count for overall process. I need to repeat all  animations from the beginning. From frame 1 to frame 5.
Thank you in advance

HTML:

```
<div class="sp-container">
        <div class="sp-content">

                <h2 class="frame-1">It's destroying the planet</h2>

                <h2 class="frame-2">It's mass, mechanized murder</h2>

                <h2 class="frame-3">You can stop it</h2>

                <h2 class="frame-4">Now!</h2>

                <h2 class="frame-5"><span>Save the planet.</span> <span>Love life.</span> <span>Go vegan.</span></h2>


        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:
.

```
sp-container {
  position:relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  background: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));

}

.sp-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;

}

.sp-container h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  line-height: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  font-size: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: transparent;
    -webkit-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
  -moz-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
  -ms-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
  animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;





}

.sp-container h2.frame-1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;

}

.sp-container h2.frame-2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.sp-container h2.frame-3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.sp-container h2.frame-4 {
  font-size: 150px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
  animation-delay: 9s;
}

.sp-container h2.frame-5 {
  -webkit-animation: none;
  -moz-animation: none;
  -ms-animation: none;
  animation: none;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;

}

.sp-container h2.frame-5 span {
  -webkit-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
  -moz-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 12s backwards;
  -ms-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
  animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 13s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 13s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 13s;
  animation-delay: 13s;
}

.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 14s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 14s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 14s;
  animation-delay: 14s;

}






/**/

@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  20%,
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInBack {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.4;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transform: scale(5);
  }
}




/**/

@-moz-keyframes blurFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  20%,
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes blurFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeInBack {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.4;
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -moz-transform: scale(5);
  }
}




/**/

@keyframes blurFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  20%,
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

@keyframes blurFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInBack {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.4;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    transform: scale(5);
  }
}
```

Comment: So you are doing animated ads, good for you. There is no way you can cycle them only if they have the same/ perfect timings, which is either hard or impossible to achieve. You should use JS to restart your animation after the last animation has ended.

Comment: @DincaAdrian thank you very much for your efforts. Unfortunately, I don't know JS :( . Could you please help?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a JS script as the following one

```
<script>
  // setting the element
  element = document.getElementById("ad");
  // reset animation
  setInterval(function() {
    // -> delete class
    element.classList.remove("animation");
    // -> triggering reflow /* The actual magic */
    // without this it wouldn't work. Try uncommenting the line and the transition won't be retriggered.
    element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;
    // -> add the animation class so the animation is restarted
    element.classList.add("animation");
  }, 7000);
  // this is the timmer which sums up the total of animation time of elements and delays calculated by you

</script>
```

Where the ad element is your parent element, and all animations are defined under the class of 
`.ad.animation .element{//animation defined here}`
Html should start already with the main element defined as following :

```
<div onclick='window.location.href="http://www.google.com"' id="ad" class="ad animation">
```

Where you change the link to whatever you want (custom or googleAds/other Ads providers) and start animation right away. The 7000 milliseconds represent the total time of your animation, change that accordingly. Hope this helps and will boost you somehow :D

Comment: Also, as a side note, if you are just begging with animations, a good library for that is http://lesshat.madebysource.com/ (that will require you to learn less, BUT that will drastically improve your productivity since you will be able to define new animations in matter of second). Also is a good library to take care of the browser compatibility for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I couldn't be sure where should I use this class **.ad.animation .element{//animation defined here}**

Comment: So, all animations are defined under the *.animation* class move all animations to take place only when the class is present. Now you understand the concept?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, so the css animation will be like that '.ad .sp-container h2.frame-1 {}' and div element like that '<div onclick='window.location.href="http://www.google.com"' id="ad" class="ad animation">' ? I couldn't make it work :/

Comment: yayy, it worked :)) in css I should use .animation class only. Thank you very much Dinca